# speed up straightforward solution using dynamic programming

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic, memoization

i recently got onto the following problem:
we consider the following array:

```
A = [2, 3, 6, 1, 6, 4, 12, 24]
```

we need to count the number of times these two conidtion are satisfied within the array:

```
A[i] * A[j] * A[k] = A[l] so that 0 <= i < j < k < l < len(A)
```

for this example the result should be 8.
example of satisfied conditions within the array:

```
2 * 3 * 1 = 6
2 * 6 * 1 = 12
6 * 1 * 4 = 24
3 * 1 * 4 = 12
```

the straightforward solution i created using python:

```
A = [2, 3, 6, 1, 6, 4, 12, 24]
result = 0
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(A)):
        for k in range(j + 1, len(A)):
            for l in range(k + 1, len(A)):
                if A[i] * A[j] * A[k] == A[l]:
                    result += 1
print(result)
```

i need to find a way to speed up the program using dynamic, maybe memoization or pre computing.

```
result = 0
for i in range(A):
    for j in range(i + 1, A):
        for k in range(j + 1, A):
             #TODO
print(result)
```

i was thinking of creating a dictionary that contains a set of dictionaries for each number, to indicate the number and its position, example:

```
memo = {
    6: {
        2: True
        4: True
    }, 
    1: {
       3: True
    },
    ...
}
```

then we check like the following:

```
result = 0
for i in range(A):
    for j in range(i + 1, A):
        for k in range(j + 1, A):
            x = A[i] * A[j] * A[k]
            if x in memo:
                result += len([z[0] for z in memo[x].items() if z[0] > k])
```

This way we will count all occurrences of the same number after the index k at once, we will not have to go through all array.

Please let me know if my optimisation is flawed, and if there's better optimisation using dynamic programming techniques such as memoization or pre computing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in optimization or dynamic programming. But what you could do to speed up your code is using `itertools.combinations` to determine all combinations of indices beforehand. This way you then only have to loop through all combinations afterwards.

The below code should be faster:

```
import itertools

# Determine combinations of indices
comb = itertools.combinations(range(len(A)),4)
result = 0
for idx in comb:
    if A[idx[0]]*A[idx[1]]*A[idx[2]] == A[idx[3]]:
        result += 1
result
```

Obviously this will not be a fast solution if `A` is of large size. But for your array it is ~2x faster

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, it seems we could have O(n^2 log n) by hashing all pair multiples and all pair divisions, where the division is a whole number. For the multiples, store a list of just the higher index of each such pair; and for the division, store a list of just the lower index of each such pair. Then iterate over each division pair and use binary search to determine how many pairs of multiples match, who's high index is lower.

```
A[i] * A[j] = A[l] / A[k]
```